# Is there a way to programmatically set gas limit?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js

My smart contract has a centralized web app as front end using Ethers.js to communicate (in a Flutter app). When I'm executing a function, I need to pass the gas limit. How can I know what is a good amount to set, so that it's not too much and it also won't run out of gas? On Rinkeby, I found the limit of 1000000 through trial&error, but I can't afford to do the same on Mainnet. I saw that when using Remix to call the function, Metamask does its own estimation, but if called through the custom frontend it just takes whatever it finds in the transaction object. So I guess I'd like to have the same estimation in my app that works through Remix.
Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/) estimates the gas automatically. Just leave the "gasLimit" field empty.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check [getFeeData](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getFeeData) int `etherjs` documentation.
2. Since the `gas` cost of solodity function is pretty much equal every time you can make average of 10, 20 calls on test net
3. You can calculate the `feePrice*gas*ethPrice` to get some approximation what it would cost

**EDIT:** Updated for an EIP-1559 transaction

Comment: You probably want to use `getFeeData` instead, since the gas price is for legacy transactions.

Comment: @Morten Yep, you are correct!